# Radial progress bar using TailwindUI

Tags: css, tailwind-css, phoenix-framework, tailwind-ui

### Background

I have a small Phoenix 1.7 app where I am trying to add a radial progress bar, using the default TailwindUI components: https://tailwindui.com/components

Unfortunately for me, I was only able to find normal progress bars:

https://flowbite.com/docs/components/progress/

Namely:

```
<div class="w-full bg-gray-200 rounded-full h-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700">
  <div class="bg-blue-600 h-2.5 rounded-full" style="width: 45%"></div>
</div>
```

The only radial progress bar I found was one using DaisyUI:

https://daisyui.com/components/radial-progress/

However, I want to avoid installing anything extra, I really just want to use the default tailwindUI and tailwindCSS that come with Phoenix 1.7

### Questions

1. Does someone know how to create a a radial progress bar component using the default setup that comes with Phoenix LiveView 1.7?
2. Am I missing some component that already does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

By checking some examples using Tailwind with Apline.js I was able to analyze the code and create a component that does exactly what I want.

This code uses only Phoniex LiveView vanilla, no extra CSS no extra anything !

**`core_components`**:

```
  @doc """
  Renders a progress bar for an ongoing operation.

  ## Examples

      <.progress_bar hidden=false progress=15 />
      <.progress_bar hidden=false progress=20 message="Activating system ..." />
      <.progress_bar hidden=false class="cool-bar" />
  """
  attr :hidden, :boolean, default: true, doc: "whether or not to show the progress bar"
  attr :progress, :integer, default: 0, doc: "the current progress of the bar"
  attr :message, :string, default: "Operation in progress ...", doc: "the message to show while the bar is progressing"
  attr :class, :string, default: nil

  def progress_bar(assigns) do

    assigns = assign(assigns, :circumference, 2 * 22 / 7 * 120)
    assigns = assign(assigns, :offset, assigns.circumference - assigns.progress / 100 * assigns.circumference)

    ~H"""
    <div class={@class} hidden={@hidden}>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
        <p class="text-lg font-semibold"><%= @message %></p>
      </div>

      <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
        <svg class="transform -rotate-90 w-72 h-72">
            <circle cx="145" cy="145" r="120" stroke-width="30" fill="transparent" class="stroke-gray-700" />

            <circle cx="145" cy="145" r="120" stroke-width="30" fill="transparent"
                stroke-dasharray={@circumference}
                stroke-dashoffset={@offset}
                class="stroke-indigo-500" />
        </svg>
        <span class="absolute text-5xl stroke-black"><%= @progress %></span>
      </div>

    </div>
    """
  end
```

Usage in **`my_app_live.heex.html`**:

```
<div class="min-h-full max-w-full mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
  <.progress_bar hidden={false} progress={40} message="Activating system ..." />
</div>
```

Will produce the following:

[image]

For more information on how I created this, feel free to check the whole story on the elixir's forum thread:

https://elixirforum.com/t/radial-progress-bar-using-tailwinui/58098/10?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have to write some custom CSS and spice it up with your tailwind classes.

You can check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eYinka/873be69fae3ef27b103681b8a9f5e379) for a custom-made circular progress bar using Tailwind.

Basically, here's what you need:

```
// custom.css

.progress-ring__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 400, 400;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.35s;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}


// component.html 
<div class="relative w-40 h-40">
  <svg class="w-full h-full" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- Background circle -->
    <circle
      class="text-gray-200 stroke-current"
      stroke-width="10"
      
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      fill="transparent"
    ></circle>
    <!-- Progress circle -->
    <circle
      class="text-indigo-500  progress-ring__circle stroke-current"
      stroke-width="10"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="40"
      fill="transparent"
      stroke-dashoffset="calc(400 - (400 * 45) / 100)"
    ></circle>
    
    <!-- Center text -->
    <text x="50" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">70%</text>

  </svg>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Goodluck!

Comment: This is a rather interesting alternative to the solution I found. Upvoted, Thanks !